# Does Terraform track Module Versions

Tags: terraform

[Here](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/files/dependency-lock) it is stated:

> At present, the dependency lock file tracks only provider
> dependencies. Terraform does not remember version selections for
> remote modules, and so Terraform will always select the newest
> available module version that meets the specified version constraints.

[Here](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/v1.1.x/commands/init) it is stated:

> Re-running init with modules already installed will install the
> sources for any modules that were added to configuration since the
> last init, but will not change any already-installed modules

For me those two statements are not aligned: if Terraform does not remember the version of a module, how can it remember, which one was used in the last init?

Comment: It uses the one it downloaded to the `.terraform/modules` directory.

Comment: and for local module it will always take the source code it finds?

Comment: Yes, but I'm still not sure what the question is. There are ways you can tell terraform which module version to download, either by specifying it in the module `source` parameter or specifying the source without the version, but using the `version` argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The subtlety here is that `terraform init` will, by default, not update any module that was previously cached in the `.terraform` directory by an earlier run of `terraform init`.

That means that *in that particular working directory* Terraform is in a sense "tracking module versions", although it's not doing it by actually remembering any version information. Instead, it just checks whether there's already a matching directory for the module package in the module cache directory and skips installing the module if so, which has the side-effect of preserving a previous selection.

However, if one of your colleagues were to run `terraform init` for the same root module on their own computer, their own `.terraform` directory would not contain your directory's cached entries, and so they will end up with the newest available version matching the given source address and version.

The dependency lock file is different because that should (if you are using Terraform as recommended in the documentation) be committed to your version control system, and so everyone working in the same repository will select the same versions unless they explicitly ask Terraform to ignore the existing locks by using `terraform init -upgrade`. In current versions of Terraform there is no equivalent of that capability for modules.